# nodejs mysql affectedRows on insert

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sql-insert

I was reading the mysql npm package documentation and was wondering about the following:

[image]

I don't understand the presence of affectedRows on an insert statement, in what scenario would affectedRows be 0? I would assume an error to be thrown when an insert statement would fail. Could anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use [INSERT with SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) addition then affectedRows can be more than 1.
Also INSERT statement in MySQL has option [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and if during insert some row was updated then AffectedRows count for this row will be 2, not 1. Also [INSERT has IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) option and in case insert was not actually done then AffectedRows will be 0 for that row.

Comment: that makes sense, however when just using the plain INSERT statement without any additions. affectedRows is basically useless since it will throw an error when affectedRows is <1 correct?

Comment: INSERT with SELECT is still just an INSERT, so it makes perfect sense imho.

Answer (score 2):

- It is useful in cases like when one is inserting data from **insert ... select** where select can have conditions so one doesn't know before hand as to how many or which rows will be actually inserted.
- There can be other cases like **insert ignore**